# E464: Ambiguous use of user-defined command

Tags: ubuntu, vim

When I try to go to the end of a file in vim by doing `:G` I get the following:

```
E464: Ambiguous use of user-defined command
```

I don't know why it's saying this. Where can I see a list of user-defined commands and potentially delete them?

Comment: It's `G`, not `:G`.

Answer (score 17):

You can get a list of user-defined commands by typing:

```
:command
```

And the reason you're getting the error is because there are two or more possible commands that match the partial command you typed. You need to type more of the command, or the full command for it to work.

You can always find out what an error message means by doing `:help` on the error number. In this case:

```
:help E464
```

Incidentally, `:G` is not an internal Vim :-command, but it is a normal mode command. You want `:$` or just `G`.